# how to download source jar file for org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Is there any way to download gradle-kotlin-dsl-6.6.1.jar source file by idea or manually with a link?
I wanted to read the source code of the functions in this dependency, I couldn't find the source code also.

Answer (score 0):

The sources JAR for this JAR (`gradle-kotlin-dsl-6.6.1.jar`) does not exist in downloadable form.  The source files are available in [Gradle's GitHub repository](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/v8.6.0/platforms/core-configuration/kotlin-dsl) though, or if you downloaded the full distribution (with sources), then under `src/kotlin-dsl/` in the distribution archive.

Bear in mind, that they moved the location for Kotlin DSL sources in the repository sometime around August 2023, so if you're looking for sources for version 6.6.1 specifically, then the source files may be located at a different path in the repository for that version.  Location within the distribution should be the same.

Answer (score -1):

I reasoned that, since the plugin is working for me, the code must've been downloaded. What I've found is that (in Android Studio under Linux), if I ctrl-click on a keyword in (anything, I think, but in this case) a build.kts file it takes me to the definition.

Doing this, I can then hover my cursor on the tab name and it shows me where the file is. Mine is way down under /.gradle, but the point is it does tell me where.

So, while I haven't found the jar file itself, I'm thinking that each of the files found like this are part of it. Does that help enough, or at least a bit?